# image convolution from ppm file

Tags: c, image, convolution, ppm

Good afternoon to everyone.
Firstly, i would like to apologize for my code - i am a real beginner in C. My problem is - i am given ppm file and i would need to store values from there into an array. I have already stored height , width and max value of color, now my idea to store a values would be the as shown at the picture - multiplying by three because it is in R G B format.
thank you for your help and please concider the fact i am a real beginner in C.

[my code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mdEP.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
printf(" %s ", argv[1]);
printf("\n");
int firstLine[2];
int width;
int next;
int enter;
int loop;
int height;
int max_color;
int pix[width][height];
int mask[3][3] = {// inicializting our given mask
    {0, -1, 0},
    {-1, 5, -1},
    {0, -1, 0}
};

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("%d ", mask[i][j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}

fscanf(fp, "%s", &firstLine);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &height);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &width);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &max_color);


printf("%p", firstLine);
printf("\n");
printf("%d ", width);
printf("\n");
printf("%d", height);
printf("\n");
printf("%d", max_color);
printf("\n");


for (i = 0; i < width * 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < height * 3; j++) {
        loop = fscanf(fp, "%d", &enter);
        pix[i][j] = enter;
        printf("%d ", enter);
    }
}

// fclose(fp);


return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Comment: please do not use images to share code! :) please copy and paste it here or a pastebin.

Comment: sorry, i am a beginner here, so i did right now. Thank you

Comment: Not sure if you were told to assume 8-bit R,G and B samples, but technically you should check the `MAX_INTENSITY` is 255 before assuming that, and if it is over 255 (most likely equal to 65535), you should be reading 16-bit samples.

Comment: I have added a comment below...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define array with unknown size, esp height and width are not initialized. You should use dynamic allocated array here, like this:

```
int ***pix;
pix = malloc(height * sizeof(int**));
for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    pix[i] = malloc(width * sizeof(int**));
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        pix[i][j] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

To correct parse the binary, you cannot use formatted input because they are for strings. You can use fread instead, e.g. to read the width:

```
fread(&width, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

Then to fill this array:

```
for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            fread(&enter, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
            pix[i][j][k] = enter;
        }
    }
}
```

This only works if what you said about ppm file's format is correct of course.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, i really appreciate that.
Unfortunatelly it doesnt work well - giving me 21755842 for all the blocks in array. We were given an input ppm file in binary coded format portable pixmap format. This kind of format has always: P6 , width, height and then constant - maximum value of intensity of pixel
and then data - RGB parts for each pixel. Each part of pixel /RGB is one Byte.

Comment: The file is in binary, so the formatted input will certainly not work!

Comment: @fluter The header is actually in ASCII, then the data follows in binary.

Comment: yes exactly, sorry for not specifing that, i was trying to understand how ppm works and everywhere it wasnt in binary like wikipedia and so. So i am very sorry, but can you at least give me an idea how would you save it then? I thought array will be the best option, as then i will have to use a mask on that...

Comment: and yes, i have a correct output when it comes to header, unfortunatelly i cant find a way how to store the rest.

Comment: not sure what's your goal of saving/store, please give more details.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah, I've read the Wikipedia page, got it now.

Comment: at the end i need to apply a mask on it so i will definitely need to save it, and then work with the data here.  I am trying to figure it out from yesterday, but still nothing

Comment: The `fread()` in the middle of the loop above is incorrect - it reads a full 4 bytes from your file for each of the Red, Green and Blue pixels, whereas your `PPM` file only contains 1 byte for Red, 1 for Green and 1 for Blue, so you should change it to `fread(&enter, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fp);`